# CSS Zoom equivalent?

Tags: css, zooming, scale

I have an img class for `retina` (2x DPI)  and using `zoom:50%` works perfectly. However the browser support is limited.

I tried `transform: scale(0.5)` but it doesn't do the same thing - it scales the image based on the wrapper div it's in (50% of div's width) rather than the image width itself.

Comment: Can you add a snippet `[<>]` of your HTML and CSS to play around with?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below elements.

-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
-o-transform: scale(0.5);
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);

Note: But this will work if the browser version should be higher.

Comment: This works for me but has some white spaces above the header

Answer (score 0):

`zoom: 50%` applied to the image seems to make it the right size, but for some reason affects the parent div as well (in Chrome at least). `transform: scale(0.5)` seems to size the image as well to the right size, if applied to the image itself.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /*zoom: 50%;*/
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="" width="300" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: Huh, it does seem that it's scaling itself using `transform` inside a div, I guess there is a random element somehow affecting it.

Comment: Could be. Transform: scale should work in itself. If it doesn't work for you, please add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, so we can have a look.